# The etymology and the Middle English spelling of "beginning"

Tags: orthography, middle-english, handwriting

This question is about historical spelling, but in my opinion the knowledge of the historical spelling relates with the etymology knowledge.

The questions are:
1. Is the fourth letter in image 1 (*y*) and the large yellow capital letter in image 2 the same letter?
2. Are the fifth and the sixth letters of the circled word in image 2 the same?

What are the precise letters in the word "beginning" in Wycliffe's Bible from [originalbibles.com](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/) (Wycliffe's Bible, from 1382 to 1395, Middle English, **page 151**, Jn.1:1)?

**Image 1**
[image: Screenshot of page from Wycliffe's Bible]
**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The title and body seem to be refering to different things.

Comment: Are you really asking how the word is spelled? (It's "bigynnyng" where I've drawn the circle, and "bigynyng" further on)

Comment: @KillingTime I have looked [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/begin#English) and saw this ( Middle English beginnen, from Old English beginnan), but the picture above, in my opinion, depict sth different

Comment: @AndrewLeach Is the word "bigynnyng" relate to the Old English or what?

Comment: Even in Shakespeare's time (Early Modern English) spelling was not particularly standardised. He spelled his own name a number of different ways.

Comment: @AndrewLeach May I ask a few more questions about the Old English spelling on this "forum" (in the new topics)?

Comment: It's not a forum; it's a site where questions get answers. Please do take a look at the [Tour](/tour) and see what's [on topic](/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](/help/dont-ask). Questions which contain everything relevant (like the image here) **and details of your own research** are better received than ones which are hastily asked.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I am not sure, that I have the right to posting here things like that image (because of copyright).

Comment: I think Wycliffe has been dead more than seventy years and the typography was created more than twenty-five years ago. In any case, even the (quite restrictive) UK Copyright Designs and Patents Act allows fair dealing for research — and this site is based in the US.

Comment: [Quadrata is the 'high-Gothic' variety of Textura, which is characterised by the consistent use of diamond-shaped feet on **'minim'** letters made up of vertical strokes **(such as i, m, n, u)**. The script is very regular and used for good quality books.](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/manuscriptsandspecialcollections/researchguidance/medievaldocuments/handwritingstyles.aspx)

Comment: Related: [How was the letter -u- written in Old English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250095/how-was-the-letter-u-written-in-old-english) *and* [What's the current scholarly opinion on the “minims” explanation for the spelling of “love”, “tongue,” etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338132/whats-the-current-scholarly-opinion-on-the-minims-explanation-for-the-spellin/351681#351681)

Comment: From the OP's comments, it seem that the question is not so much about etymology but about calligraphy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In my opinion, so many recursion steps are need to do to undestand the answer on my question, can you please shortly tell: Are the first letter on the image 2 and the forth letter in the word "bigynnyng" the same? Are the fifth and the sixth letters in the word "bigynnyng" the same? Yes or Not. Hope for understanding.

Comment: The word in the first image is written "**bigynnyng**", while "beginning" in the second image appears to be written as  **bigyunyng** (only one "n"). You need to make this distinction, spelling versus etymology, clear IN the question, not in the comments. If the title asks about etymology that's the type of answer you're going to get. So, WRITE the word as it appears to you IN the question..

Comment: In the second image, it's *bigynnyng.* The *n* that appears to be *u* is badly written.

Comment: This question really has absolutely nothing at all to do with etymology. It’s not an uninteresting question, but the etymology of the word _beginning_ is not relevant to it at all.

Answer (score 2):

The [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (subscription required), for the word "beginning, *n*" we find:

> Forms:  Also bi-, bygyn(n)yng; ME -unge.

Spelling was much less consistent in the 14th century than today.

Comment: I thing that the fourth letter in the word "bigynnyng" is similar to the big yellow capital letter on the image 2 above (page 61), but this capital letter and the following letter "e", in my opinion, are relate to the modern article "the" (Old English þē), the first letter of which is a consonant but not a vowel.

Comment: Also it seems to me, that the fifth and the sixth letters of the word "bigynnyng" are not the same.

Comment: @INeedHelp Yes, they are very similar, but not identical. Thorn (þ) was written more or less how we’d write a lowercase p, with a slightly pointier bowl (i.e., long vertical stem with descender straight down + ɔ shape as the bowl), whereas y was written closer to how we write it now as well (i.e., short vertical x-height stroke + pointy bowl with a descender tapering to the left). A lowercase p would be much like þ, but with a rounder bowl and usually some kind of serif at the bottom of the stem.